# Batch file help (Loops and Menus)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I currently have this menu:

```
echo What would you like to do?
echo.
echo Choice
echo.
echo 1 Delete File
echo 2 Ignore File
echo.

:choice
set /P C=[1,2]?
if "%C%"=="2" goto Deleting
if "%C%"=="1" goto IgnoreFile
goto choice
```

Although it does not seem to work, when I select an option e.g. 2 it will not goto the :IgnoreFile section, instead it will continue the script (i.e. continue with the next command in the file, after entering my choice)

Very thrustrating, I am not sur

Comment: that works just fine here, but be careful: your if statement and your menu disagree (menu 1 == Delete, if 1 == Ignore)

Comment: @Mat I believe that answers OP's question. Post it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your problem, you should make a end mark to skip a sequence of your script.

```
@echo off
echo What would you like to do?
echo.
echo Choice
echo.
echo 1 Delete File
echo 2 Ignore File
echo.

:choice
set /P C=[1,2]?
if "%C%"=="1" goto Deleting
if "%C%"=="2" goto IgnoreFile
goto choice


:Deleting
echo Deleting
[your code]
goto end

:IgnoreFile
echo IgnoreFile
[your code]
goto end

:end
```

the "goto end" at the end of each case allow you to skip the reste of the script. Don't forget to make a ":end" part at the very last line of your script.

If you don't use "goto end" and selected the "Deleting" case, the deleting part would be executed and the script would keep on going and run the "IgnoreFile" case

Comment: "goto :end" does not require an existing ":END" label at the end of the script.  If one exists, it will jump to it as intended.  If there isn't, the script will be stopped, much like "exit /b"